# Remove extension using str_replace when echoing using glob

Tags: php, string, glob

I have a page where I want to list all of the documents a user has uploaded, and want to remove the extension from each item that is listed.

This list will contain potentially limitless filetypes, so the method that I was using of manually specifying and replacing the extension with nothing, will take too long.

I also tried to do a `str_replace` on `.*` so that anything after the `.` is replaced, but that did not seem to work.

Here's what I have:

```
<?php 
$chkdir = is_dir("/secure/user uploads/".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."");
$path = "$chkdir/";
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) { 
$result = str_replace("$path","", $filename); 
$result = str_replace(".pdf","", $result); 
$result = str_replace(".db","", $result); 
echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

You can see near the end that I specified PDF and DB as file extensions to remove, but I want to try a more general approach, and remove all file extensions.

Can anyone advise with this?

Comment: Why not `explode` on `.`, remove the last element, then `implode` on `.`?  (Edge case: no extension means after the explode, there's only one element) 
It's probably not the most efficient method, but it makes sense and doesn't involve regex.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I saw someone doing something kind of similar with this, but i'm not that familiar with it so couldn't apply to my situation. will read up on it and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php).

From the PHP manual example:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
echo $path_parts['filename']; // lib.inc
```

Applied to your situation:

```
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) { 
  $path_parts = pathinfo($filename); 
  $result = $path_parts['filename']; 
  echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: this seems perfect, I will go and give it a go now and see how I get on. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all possible extension into an array and replace it looping through it. something like:
            $ext = array(pdf, db, etc ...);

Comment: Where is the list of "all possible extensions"? Also you may have missed the line in the question where he said he didn't want to do this: "This list will contain potentially limitless filetypes, so the method that I was using of manually specifying and replacing the extension with nothing, will take too long."

Comment: The idea of an array has crossed my mind, but for a slightly different purpose. @jprofitt is correct in saying that removing extensions using an array is to much of a manual process for me im afraid. I will investigate using an array to only display my specified filetypes, that way I could potentially use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Split by '.' and remove last item, then put it back together.

```
<?php 
$chkdir = is_dir("/secure/user uploads/".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."");
$path = "$chkdir/";
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) { 
$result = str_replace("$path","", $filename);
$t = explode('.',$result);
if(count($t) > 1) array_pop($t);
$result = implode('.',$t);
echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>"; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$path = "./"; 
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) {  
$result = str_replace("$path","", $filename);  
$result = strip_ext($result, "php", "js");  
echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". $result . "</a></li><tr>";  
}  


function strip_ext($file) {
    $args = func_get_args();

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($args); $i++) {
        $ext = $args[$i];

        $ext_pos = strrpos($file, '.' . $ext);

        //The extension must exist and be at the end of the file name.
        if ($ext_pos != false && $ext_pos + strlen($ext) == strlen($file) - 1) {
            return(substr($file, 0, $ext_pos));
        }
    }

    return($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Release 5.2 (March 5, 2013) added `PATHINFO_FILENAME` constant.
- for filename without path and extension

In 1 line of code:

```
$filename = pathinfo("$path", PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

your:

```
foreach (glob("$path*") as $filename) { 
    echo "<li><a href='" . $filename ."'/>". pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "</a></li><tr>"; 
}
```